# Variable subsystem implementation in Simulink 2007a

Tags: simulink

I've seen that it's already implemented in Matlab R2013 in the form of Variant Subsystems, but budget and convenience don't show the upgrade necessary yet:

I am seeking a subsystem in which a concrete implementation can be selected prior to running the simulation, in Matlab R2007a.

A bunch of enabled subsystems along with a switch block connected to a masked variable would do the trick, however the whole family of selectable implementations must coexist inside the "container" subsystem.

Any workaround, other than upgrading to R2013?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with the following workaround.

1- Include all the possible implementations in a Library

2- Create a Configurable Subsystem block in the Library and edit it to include all the desired implementations

3- Right clicking in a Configurable Subsystem instance will show the "Block Choice" option where the desired implementation can be chosen.

Regardless of differences that may exist with respect to the Variant Subsystem solution when it comes to code generation, RT targets etc..., this solution works for me.

Comment: +1. I have used this for many years and it works well. There is even a programmatic equivalent to the right-clicking action for selecting the block choice, but I can't remember what it is off-hand.

Comment: set_param('your/block/here', 'BlockChoice','MYSUBSYSTEM1')